# Finding the difference between times in different columns through a CSV file

Tags: python, csv, datetime, time, import-from-csv

So, I have attempted this quite a few times; this has been my latest attempt:

```
import csv
import collections
import datetime

print "Please type file name to open:"
fileName = raw_input('> ')
print ""


incidents = collections.Counter()
with open(fileName) as input_file:
    for row in csv.reader(input_file, delimiter=','):       
        d0 = str(incidents[row[8]])
        d1 = str(incidents[row[7]])
        date0 = datetime.datetime.strptime(d0, "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S").date()
        date1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(d1, "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S").date()
        delta = (date0 - date1).days
        print delta
```

Essentially, I have a CSV file with two columns of data. Both are dates in this format: "1/21/2014 10:51 AM". I need to be able to take the difference of the dates and convert it into a decimal.

For instance if column 1, row 1 was "1/21/2014 10:51 AM" and column 2, row 1 was "9/4/2012  2:56:29 AM". Then the final output should be "504.33".

I can post other attempts/more in depth of an explanation if needed.

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: How do I find the difference between two dates/times as stated above through a CSV file?

Comment: `%H Two digit representation of the hour in 24-hour format` should probably be `%l`. and you need `%p`, too

Comment: @user32... you present a solution, yet don't explain how it does not fit your need. How is anyone supposed to guess what is wrong with your code ?

Comment: Also, `1/21/2014` VS `%Y/%m/%d` that seems quite obvious that the order is wrong. and it should be %e. please read the documentation for the functions you are using.

Comment: Your input timestamps are inconsistent (one has seconds, the other does not). Is there any consistency per column or are dates randomly missing seconds?

Comment: @njzk2 When I run the code, I get the following error: "ValueError: time data '0' does not match format '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'". Does this help?

Comment: @MartijnPieters all dates are consistent.

Comment: @user3266742: It means you picked the wrong format, it does not match your input timestamp. But your timestamps are inconsistent anyway.

Comment: @user3266742 yes. surprisingly, giving more specific information about the error you encounter does help solving said error. Albeit, in this case, just read my previous comments regarding the date format. (and make your dates consistent)

Comment: @user3266742: I just told you your dates are inconsistent in your post. Did you forget to include the seconds in your first timestamp?

Comment: And why are you showing us an expected output of 504.33 but strip off the time? To get a day fraction you need to take into account the time as well, not just the dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the date you provided, one of those two format should work.

With seconds:

```
"%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p"
```

Without seconds:

```
"%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p"
```

Read more about the strptime format behaviour here: [Datetime documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

It's well explained with samples of what it will parse.

---

> For instance if column 1, row 1 was "1/21/2014 10:51 AM" and column 2, row 1 was "9/4/2012 2:56:29 AM". Then the final output should be "504.33".

According to this:

```
date0 = datetime.datetime.strptime(d0, "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
date1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(d1, "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p")
delta = date0 - date1
return delta.days + (delta.seconds / 86400.0) # 60 seconds in 60 minutes in 24 hours
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided your datetime stamps are actually consistent (and are not missing the seconds, like in your `"1/21/2014 10:51 AM"` sample), then you need to use the correct format to parse the timestamps:

```
date0 = datetime.datetime.strptime(d0, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
date1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(d1, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
delta = date0 - date1
delta = delta.days + (delta.seconds / 86400.0)  # add day fraction
print delta
```